# Splitting a value from sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, split

this is for my A2 computing project. I want this code to get data from PupilPremiumTableNew and PupilTable where PupilID equals an input which will be got from another function and will be equal to AllID. Multiple PupilID's may be passed into the function at once, which is why AllID is a list that is iterated over, meaning that the program can find multiple pupils, not just one, in one call of the function.

The data collected from PupilTable and PupilPremiumNew will be combined (as seen in the code) and then passed into tabulate (A downloaded *add on* to python that allows me to display tables easily and look reasonably good). At the moment however tabulate thinks that every digit (including , and brackets left in) are separate inputs, so I end up with my data spread across multiple columns. 
The problem will, I assume, be with the brackets and/or the data type of AllInfo. I'm not sure what to do, I've tried a number of things but they haven't worked, such as using join and split, although I may have used them incorrectly.

```
    while Count < Length:
    PupilID = AllID[Count]
    PupilID = str('.'.join(str(x) for x in PupilID))
    with sqlite3.connect("PupilPremiumTableNew.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PupilPremiumTableNew where PupilID =?",(PupilID,))
        AllPupils = str(cursor.fetchone())
        cursor.execute("SELECT PupilSurname, PupilName, SeasonOfBirth,SpecialEducationalNeeds,YearGroup FROM PupilTable where PupilID =?",(PupilID,))
        PupilTableInfo = str(cursor.fetchall())
        if AllPupils == 'None':
            Count = Count + 1
        else:
            AllInfo = [PupilTableInfo + AllPupils]
            Count = Count + 1
            print(AllInfo)
```

The returned information is:

```
["[('Meow', 'James', 'Spring', 'y', 1)](1, '1a', '1a', '1a', 'Autumn', 1, 'Small groups', 'Large groups', 'One on one', 1)"]
```

which comes from two files, PupilTable and PupilPremiumTableNew. These are both relational databases, although I don't think that is necessary.

Thanks, If you want the tabulate output comment this asking for it, I didn't put it in because I didn't think it was relevant because this isn't an error with tabulate but with the brackets.

Thanks Devilb77

Answer (score 0):

I've realised, after talking to some friends that I want to use an inner join in sqlite3. Anyone with a similar problem should look up what an inner join is and the two other types of join. It makes this much simpler.

Thanks
Devilb77